# apt-get works with sudo but not with root

Tags: apt, sudo, root, vagrant, apt-cacher

I'm setting up a Vagrant box with Ubuntu 20.04 behind a proxy and using apt-cacher as repository.

In the Vagrantfile I run (as root) these commands in this order:

```
apt-get -qq install -y docker docker-compose
...
apt-get -qq install -y mariadb-server mariadb-client
...
apt-get -qq install -y subversion wget libxrender1 libxtst6 libxi6 libgtk2.0-0 libidn11 libglu1-mesa
```

The second command, and **only the second** command does not work. The output has a bunch of 404, but I cannot paste it here because "it looks like spam"...

Inside che Box I have the following behaviour.

This command works: `$ sudo apt-get update`
This command also works: `$ sudo apt-get install mariadb-server mariadb-client`

This command *launched as root* **does not** work: `# apt-get update`.

This is some of the output:

```
Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
...
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository '...' is no longer signed.
...
```

This command *launched as root* **does not** work: `# apt-get install mariadb-client mariadb-server`
With same 404 output as before.

What is going on?

Comment: The root account in Ubuntu is not enabled by default. That could be the cause. Prefer to use `sudo`.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. With root I was able to run two apt-get install and a bunch of other programs (snap, node, etc). The issues are with update, installation of mariadb and a couple of other software, but it's not the repository beacuse sudo works fine...